# Should [political-commentary] be made a synonym of [media]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

There are three questions tagged [political-commentary](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/political-commentary).

1. [Is there any reason politicians don't talk about internal affairs while abroad?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/33918/26455)
2. [How should one address concerns to a parliamentary representative?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/12179/26455)
3. [Does commentary on interviews have more effect on voters than interviews themselves?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/10984/26455)

Questions 1 is about media interviews.

Question 2 is about citizen engagement and is unrelated to media. I suggest removal of [political-commentary](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/political-commentary).

Question 3 is about reactions to media commentary.